# Where should I put an html wrapper element in a React Project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am starting with react. So I have this simple project with [bootstrap](https://github.com/josuevalrob/React-bootstrap/tree/master/src)

I want to reuse an HTML structure:

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, everytime that I call this structure 3 div's will wrap my child element. right?.

At the beginning I create something like this in my "[header](https://github.com/josuevalrob/React-bootstrap/blob/master/src/components/Header.js)" component

```
const Wrapper = (props) => (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                  {props.children}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
)
```

And was easy to call that element from the class:

```
function HeaderContent (props) {
  return (
  <SimpleWrapper>
    <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
      <div className="site-heading">
          <h1>{props.h1title}</h1>
        <span className="subheading">{props.spantitle}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </SimpleWrapper>
  )
}
```

But now, I want to recall the wrapper from other components. What should I do? 
My solution was to create a separate component called: [Wrapper.js](https://github.com/josuevalrob/React-bootstrap/blob/master/src/helper/Wrapper.js) and declare my wrapper inside it. **Is this viable?**

thanks, and sorry for the dummy question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The premise of react is to break down the UI into independent and reusable components, so your proposed solution of adding a 'Wrapper' component is correct.